# Read Only linked table in Access to a SQL view - does not work

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2012

I have an ODBC connection created in MS Access 365. This is used to create a linked table in Access to a view in my SQL DB. I am using a SQL login to authenticate with SQL DB. The login has the datareader role set for that DB

If I make any changes to a record in the linked table in Access, those changes are also made in the SQL DB.

How can I avoid any changes in the Access linked table being propagated into the SQL DB?

Comment: The SQL login must have additional permissions on the instance. Have you checked the other database roles to see if they're there (eg datawriter, db_owner, etc)? Have you checked the server level roles? (eg sysadmin)

Comment: We must be missing a detail here. Editing data in some access table does not out of the blue all of sudden start editing some data on sql server. How can a form bound to a access table start updating some table on SQL server?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal It actually does. OP is talking about *linked* tables in access, where you can open the table and "edit" rows directly in the access "table", which will then use what I believe is an update cursor in the background to modify the SQL table when you finish your editing (with a pompt something like `"this will result in x records being changed"`, and then an optimistic concurrency failure message if data has changed in the meantime.

Comment: ah,I miss read the question.

Comment: @allmhuran I get no prompt when rows are updated, it just happens. I can check the SQL DB, and they have been updated, with no prompt in SQL DB or Access

Comment: The prompt typically happens when you modify a large number of rows. It's like, "warning, this will cause 1000 records to change". If you just change a few rows it doesn't issue a warning, as far as I can recall. But, in any case, the issue is still just one of permissions in the database. Putting a user in the "datareader" role doesn't mean they can *only* read, it means they can read. They could also be a member of other roles that give them additional permissions. This issue is not being caused by MS acess, it is entirely a SQL Server permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trigger to the view like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MySampleView_Trigger_OnInsertOrUpdateOrDelete]
ON dbo.MySampleView
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('You are not allow to update this view!', 16, 1)    
END
```

You can also in a pinch add a union query, but it is somewhat ugly - you have to match up the column types. Eg:

```
ALTER VIEW dbo.MySampleView
as
SELECT col1, col2 FROM dbo.MySampleTable
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL WHERE 1 =0
```

You can also create a new schema. Say dboR  (for read only).
Add this new schema to the database. Then add the schema to the sql user/logon your using for this database. And then set the permissions to the schema to read only.

You have to re-create the view and choose the read-only schema for this view. On the access client side, I in most cases remove the schema default "dbo_" and just use the table (or view name) - you can thus continue to use the same view name you have been using in Access.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply , I am not allowed to create a new schema or a trigger in the DB. It is a production DB, so cannot be tampered with like this. Im just surprised that an ODBC link in Access can update a SQL DB, even though the user only has a DataReader role...

Comment: Well that 3rd option of a view with a union query thus could work - not all to clean, but is a possible.